# Having trouble reading JSON files in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to make a website that reads a JSON file from my computer.
Instead of displaying the file's information, I only get [Object object].

```js
const response = await fetch('./AppData/LocalLow/WilhelmsenStudios/ReEntry/Export/Apollo/outputLGC.json');
let program = await response.json();

document.getElementById('program').innerHTML = program;
```

This is what I tried to use to solve the problem.

I am not using any Javascript frameworks.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('program').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(program);
```